# How do i track app installs in android

Tags: android

We are making an android app which will reward user for inviting their friends. we are having hard time to achieve this.

I know some apps are doing this referral and invite system where a user share his unique referral link and his friend click and install the app , when his friend done installing the app the user gets it reward.

I don't understand how it works. Please Explain.

for example, this is a referral campaign of amazon app and my friend told me to install it via this link so that he will get my referral. http://mcent.com/ref/8ZR287/

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this, here are my two cents:

- In your application, as soon as the user installs the app, you can probably make an API call to YOUR server - where you keep track of installs?
- Now, you will need to find away to get the Referral Code which will help you ID the referrer in your server for a reward.
- Perhaps in that same table (in your server), each time you get notified of a referral, you increment a counter and reward the referrer?
- Obviously, you need to generate a new referral code each time a new user installs your APP - might have to ID the device KEY that is unique. Then their email address? I am sure there is more to this!

I hope this helps! Good luck and let me know how it goes!